# Can't scrape all of ul tags from a table

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape all of proxy ips from this site : https://proxy-list.org/english/index.php but i can only get one ip at most
here is my code :

```
from helium import *
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   url = 'https://proxy-list.org/english/index.php'
   browser = start_chrome(url, headless=True)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
   proxies = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'table'})
   for ips in proxies:
   print(ips.find('li', {'class':'proxy'}).text)
```

i tried to use ips.find_all but it didn't work.

Comment: Seeing the `javascript` tag added to the question, are you looking for a alternative JavaScript approach to retrieving the ip addresses too or?

Comment: Nah sorry that was a mistake

Comment: Why are you using selenium/helium **and** beautifulsoup? selenium/helium already has parsing capabilities and you should be using that instead. The proxies are generated by javascript and hence aren't present in the `page_source`. You can verify this by checking the page source in your browser.

Comment: Use selenium/helium to wait for the elements to appear and extract them afterwards.

Comment: Tbh i'm very new to this so i don't exactly know what i'm doing , i used this video as a guide : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=onlQ7fL4ey8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://proxy-list.org/english/index.php'

pagecontent = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.pagecontent, 'html.parser')
maintable = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'table'})
for div_element  in maintable:
    rows = div_element.find_all('li', class_='proxy')
    for ip in rows:
        print(ip.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, the following is one of the ways how you can fetch those proxies using requests module and Beautifulsoup library:

```
import re
import base64
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://proxy-list.org/english/index.php'

def decode_proxy(target_str):
    converted_proxy = base64.b64decode(target_str)
    return converted_proxy.decode()

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
for tr in soup.select("#proxy-table li.proxy > script"):
    proxy_id = re.findall(r"Proxy[^']+(.*)\'",tr.contents[0])[0]
    print(decode_proxy(proxy_id))
```

First few results:

```
62.80.180.111:8080
68.183.221.156:38159
189.201.134.13:8080
178.60.201.44:8080
128.199.79.15:8080
139.59.78.193:8080
103.148.216.5:80
```