# How to scrape an specific td tag from a table?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the proxy ip number from this site : https://advanced.name/freeproxy?ddexp4attempt=2
but i'm having difficulty in scraping only the td tag that contains the ip addresses.
here is my code :

```
from helium import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for x in range(1,10):
  url = 'https://advanced.name/freeproxy?ddexp4attempt=2&page='
  browser = start_chrome(url+str(x), headless=True)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
  proxies = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'table-responsive'})
  for ips in proxies:
   rows = ips.find_all('td')
  for ip in rows:
     print(ip.text)
```

Comment: You just asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67043397/6503329).
Please refrain from asking multiple similar questions, until you have tried something yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the `tr` which have the attribute `data-ip` in them.

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://proxy-list.org/english/index.php'

pagecontent = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.pagecontent, 'html.parser')

def filter_tr(element):
    if element.name == 'tr':
       if element.has_attr('data-ip'):
          return True
    return False
    
trs_with_data_ip = soup.find_all(filter_tr)

for tr in trs_with_data_ip:
   print(tr.text)
```